# Pandas plots using Bokeh server?

Tags: python, bokeh

Is it possible to show and update Pandas plots in Bokeh without using show()? Are there any examples of this online? I can't seem to find any. For example, something like:

```
def bar_plot(fig, source):
    p = pd.DataFrame()
    p = p.from_dict(source.data)

    fig = p.plot.bar()
    return fig

def update_data():
    data = source.data
    data['y'] = random.sample(range(0,100),len(data['y']))
    source.data = data

button.on_click(update_data)
source = ColumnDataSource(data)

fig = bar_plot(fig, source)
layout = layout([[button,fig]])
curdoc().add_root(layout)
```

Comment: Why do you want to use bar over vbar for? If your data is in a dataframe you can easily convert it to a ColumnDataSource and use the method I posted - which you copied here and changed ?

Comment: Your method works for me. I want to make a simple app which has two tabs - one to plot a bar chart, and one to plot a word cloud. I'm just trying to figure out how to define and call my own plotting function that will plot things besides the Bokeh built in Bar, vbar, etc. But it sounds like it's not easy to do.

Comment: Oh as in you wanted to plot in other libraries and pass these to bokeh, sorry I misunderstood that. If you really want to use other plots that dont take a bokeh source - you can manually update the charts each time by recreating them.

Comment: @Okonomiyaki How is this done?

Comment: Will make a test example when i get home later.

Comment: I added a solution to your other post as an edit.

Answer (score 0):

Pandas' built-in `.plot` method uses Matplotlib to generate images. The Bokeh server has no way of synchronizing or updating MPL plots across the Python/JS boundary. The Bokeh server can only show and update plots created using native Bokeh APIs (i.e. you can create a bar plot from your data frame using [`Figure.vbar`](http://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/plotting.html#bars) or similar Bokeh functions).

Comment: Thank you! I wanted to create a simple app with two tabs - one showing a bar plot, and one with a word cloud. I know of ways to make word clouds outside of Bokeh, but is this possible to do *in* Bokeh?

Comment: There's a few possibilities. Not sure any of them are perfect. But SO is not very good for speculative discussion so I'd suggest the [public mailing list](https://groups.google.com/a/continuum.io/forum/#!forum/bokeh) is a better place to discuss that